# NSView drawRect interfering with NSButton hover

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview, nsbutton

It's best explained by these two pictures. The first picture shows an nsbutton that has not yet been hovered, the second shows the same nsbutton when I have hovered over it.

As you can see, the NSView outer bezier path seems to be drawn on the button as well, for whatever reason. The button is a normal NSButton instance, no subclass.

[image]

[image]

Here's my custom NSView :

```
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{    
    NSBezierPath *path;

    path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [path fill];

    rect.size.width -= 10;
    rect.size.height -= 10;
    rect.origin.x += 5;
    rect.origin.y += 5;

    path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
    [path fill];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSButton *commandButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(90, 50, 100, 18)];

    [commandButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
    [commandButton setBordered:YES];
    [commandButton setTitle:@"Test!"];
    [commandButton setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"LucidaGrande" size:14.0]];
    [commandButton setBezelStyle:NSInlineBezelStyle];

    [self addSubview:commandButton];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawing system passes in the rectangle of the view that needs to be redrawn as the single parameter to `drawRect:` You're using that rectangle unconditionally for the path, `path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];`, assuming that this rect is always the view's full bounds rect. This is not the case. When the button is being hovered over, its *frame* is the portion of your view which has been invalidated and needs redrawing, and that's what `rect` is.

You should either test `rect` to make sure it's appropriate to be used for the path, or -- easier and just fine unless you're having measurable drawing-related performance issues -- always use the view's bounds for the outline path.

```
path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:[self bounds]];
```

The drawing context is going to clip the drawing to the rect it asked for anyways.

Comment: Ah great, thanks for the explanation. If I understand correctly, I could also check to see if the rect passed is the same size as bounds, if it isn't, then I don't need to do any drawing at all. (then it's a button being hovered or something else).

Comment: No, in this specific case you'll need to redraw that white background -- the button also draws outside its oval, but inside its frame.

Comment: Oh yes, due it's transparent edges. Thank you for the clear explanation.